# Is Lehmer's polynomial solvable?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, galois-theory

The degree 10 polynomial
$$\displaystyle x^{10} + x^9 - x^7 - x^6 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + x + 1$$

given by D.H. Lehmer in 1933 has the property that its largest real root, $\beta = 1.176280 \cdots$ is the smallest known Salem number. Moreover, it is a folklore conjecture that $\beta$ is in fact the smallest Salem number.

However, it is curious that one cannot find a reference for the explicit value of $\beta$. I suspect that this is because Lehmer's polynomial is not solvable. Is this the case? If so, is there a reference/relatively simple argument? Furthermore, if Lehmer's polynomial is in fact not solvable, then what is its Galois group?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Magma quickly computes that it's a nonsolvable group of order 1920.

Comment: What is meant by explicit value? Probably the most explicit you can get is the description of $\beta$ you gave...

Comment: @PerAlexandersson I was hoping that such a nice polynomial would be solvable, and therefore one can find an explicit algebraic expression for $\beta$

Comment: Quintic equations are solvable by radicals *and* modular functions. As for Galois groups $G$ of irreducible polynomials $P \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with small Mahler measure, there are results to the effect that either $G$ is "large" or $P = Q(x^m)$ for a large $m$. So no surprise that the polynomial with smallest known Mahler measure has a large Galois group (as large as possible for a reciprocal polynomial).

Comment: @rlo I am surprised that the Galois group is not the whole hyperoctahedral group!

Comment: ("...or $P$ is cyclotomic," I must add in my comment above.)

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov If it is really of order 1920, it is half the order of the hyperoctahedral group on five letters, so NOT as large as possible...

Comment: @IgorRivin: Indeed, I did not check this. It is pretty big anyway.

Comment: @IgorRivin I agree, it's a bit curious.  I could presumably construct a clumsy proof that it's not the full hyperoctahedral, but I wonder if there's a better reason.  (I am inclined to trust Magma.)

Comment: @igor
If you run computations on Galois groups of reciprocal polynomials of degree 2n, you'll find that having a "half full" Galois group is quite common.  The "full" group is $C_2 \wr S_n$, corresponding to the "full permutation module" for $S_n$ over $\mathbb{F}_2$, whereas the "half full" group corresponds to the "standard module" (of dimension $n-1$).  It was shown by McKee and Christopoulos that these two situations are the only ones that can happen for Salem numbers (although the $S_n$ can be replaced by a smaller transitive group of degree $n$.

Comment: @BobbyGrizzard This is quite surprising, given, e.g., the results of Davis, S.(1-RTG); Duke, W.(1-RTG); Sun, X.(1-RTG)
Probabilistic Galois theory of reciprocal polynomials. 
Exposition. Math. 16 (1998), no. 3, 263–270. 
11K99 (11R32), which would indicate that a smaller Galois group is fairly unlikely...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Lehmer's polynomial is symmetrical,
so $x + x^{-1} =: y$ satisfies a polynomial of half the degree.
It turns out that this is the quintic $y^5 + y^4 - 5y^3 - 5y^2 + 4y + 3 = 0$, 
whose Galois group is the unsolvable $S_5$ (for instance, it's irreducible
$\bmod 2$ and decomposes as $(y^2-2y-1)(y^3-2y^2+2y+2)$ $\bmod 5$,
so the Galois group is a subgroup of $S_5$ of order divisible by $30$ that contains an odd permutation,
and the only such subgroup is $S_5$ itself).  Hence Lehmer's polynomial
is not solvable either.

[It turns out that $y$ generates the totally real quintic field
of third-smaller discriminant $36497$.
By the way, even if a polynomial *is* solvable, exhibiting a
solution in radicals may not be of much use; for instance,
the Salem root of $x^8 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + 1 = 0$ satisfies
$x + x^{-1} = y$ where $y$ is a solution of the quartic
$y^4 - 4y^2 - y + 1 = 0$ with Galois group $S_4$,
but even though this group (and thus also the octic
$x^8 - x^5 - x^4 - x^3 + 1$) is solvable I doubt that you
really want to ponder the explicit formula for $x$
involving things like the cube roots of $187/54 \pm \sqrt{-1957/108}$ . . .]

Comment: "a subgroup of $S_5$ of order divisible by $30$, and the only such subgroup is $S_5$ itself".. I guess such things happen even to the best of us :)

Comment: Oops, corrected now.  I noticed this soon after posting
(but by then I was e-incommunicado for an hour or so).
I had already checked that the Galois group is not contained in $A_5$
(either because the discriminant is not square, or because the
cycle structure $\{2,3\}$ is odd), and forgot to mention this argument
that the Galois group cannot be $A_5$.  Not that it matters for the
present application because $A_5$ is also unsolvable . . .

Comment: Why is the homomorphism from the Galois group of the degree 10 Lehmer polynomial P(x) given by the OP to the Galois group of your degree 5 polynomial Q(y) is surjective?

Comment: @YCor If $M/L/K$ is a tower of fields, with $M$ and $L$ both Galois over $K$, then $Gal(M/K) \to Gal(L/K)$ is always surjective. Once proves this very early in a Galois theory course; there are a couple of different routes.

Comment: If you insist on fully expanding them in all their glory, expressions such as the Salem root $x$ in the second paragraph are indeed rather fearsome, but they are not so bad if obtained in a sequence of steps, such as (I hope I got this right):
$$ \eqalign{a_1 &= (748 + 12 i \sqrt{5871})^{1/3}\cr
     a_2 &= \sqrt{a_1 + 16 + 112/a_1}\cr
   a_3 &= \sqrt{12 \sqrt{6}/a_2 + 32 - a_1 - 112/a_1}\cr
   y &= (a_2 + a_3) \sqrt{6}/12\cr
   x &= \left(y + \sqrt{y^2-4}\right)/2\cr}$$

Comment: @YCor already answered by **David Speyer**, but not necessary for the original question once you know that solvable Galois $\Leftrightarrow$ solvable by radicals: clearly if $x$ satisfied this condition then so would $y = x + x^{-1}$.